# Type mismatch Error when initializing variables

Tags: excel, runtime-error, type-mismatch, vba

I am having this really strange error in excel VBA that keeps showing up. I used the codes below

```
Public psword, oldpsword As Integer


Public Sub Auto_Open()

psword = Sheets("Main Menu").Cells(55, 1)
oldpsword = psword
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Protect Password:=psword
Next ws

End Sub
```

Whenever the code goes to the line "oldpsword = psword" an error message pops up showing Run-time '13:' type mismatch error. How can i fix it?

Comment: In line `Public psword, oldpsword As Integer` only `oldpsword` is `Integer` while `psword` is `Variant`. Redim it `Public psword As integer, oldpsword As Integer`

Comment: I agree with simoco that you need to fix your `Dim` statement.  However, I suspect the problem is that `Cells(55,1)` does not contain an integer.  A variant can contain anything so `psWord = ...` is OK but `oldpsword = psword` fails because the value in `psword` cannot be converted to a integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
Public psword, oldpsword As Integer
```

with

```
Dim psword as Long, oldpsword as Long
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a general comment here as simoco and Gary's Student have got you laced up... If your passwords might be alphanumeric (a little foresight here might save you debug hours in the future, especially if your client is getting the passwords wrong haha), then you may want to use a combination of `variant` and the `CStr` (http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cstr.php):

```
Public psword As Variant, oldpsword As Variant

Public Sub Auto_Open()

psword = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main Menu").Cells(55, 1)
oldpsword = psword
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Protect Password:=CStr(psword)
Next ws

End Sub
```